kreuzwerker/docker wait for postgresql in another container to start
I have a terraform project, where I want to start up my environment by using "kreuzwerker/docker" 3.0.2 as a terraform provider. Inside my docker container being started I have the problem, that my backend container does not wait for my postgresql container to being ready to accept connections. How can I achieve that properly?
database
resource "docker_container" "postgres" {
  provider = docker.database_server
  name = "postgres"
  image = docker_image.postgres.image_id
  env = [ 
    "POSTGRES_USER=postgres",
    "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres",
    "POSTGRES_DB=postgres"
   ]
   ports {
     ip = <some_ip>
     external = 5432
     internal = 5432
   }
}

backend
resource "docker_container" "backend" {
  provider = docker.backend_server
  name = "backend"
  image = docker_image.backend.image_id
}


I must ask: are you sure you want to manage docker with terraform (as opposed to docker compose, swarm or k8s, for example)? That sounds quite painful and translates to one line of compose file...

(however, terraform's depends_on meta argument may work here - I never tried it with docker so won't try posting this as an answer)

docker-compose is not applicable as docker runs on different servers and not just a single instance. I expect swarm and k8s to be overengineering for the targeted scale.

With these two resources as shown in your question, Terraform has no way to know that docker_container.backend depends on docker_container.postgres.
Although Terraform normally infers dependencies automatically based on references, in this case there doesn't seem to be any good reason for docker_container.backend to use any attributes of docker_container.postgres and so this is an example of a "hidden dependency" that you can specify using the depends_on meta-argument.
resource "docker_container" "postgres" {
  provider = docker.database_server

  name  = "postgres"
  image = docker_image.postgres.image_id
  env = [ 
    "POSTGRES_USER=postgres",
    "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres",
    "POSTGRES_DB=postgres"
  ]
  ports {
    ip       = "..."
    external = 5432
    internal = 5432
  }
}

resource "docker_container" "backend" {
  depends_on = [docker_container.postgres]
  provider   = docker.backend_server

  name  = "backend"
  image = docker_image.backend.image_id
}

However, adding depends_on only tells Terraform that it should wait until the Docker provider reports that it has finished creating docker_container.postgres. If the provider reports success before your Postgres server has finished starting up then you may still have a similar problem. Terraform cannot "see into" your Docker container, so it must rely on the Docker provider to report when the container is ready.
I'm not familiar with this provider in particular, but its documentation implies that the must_run argument (which is true by default) causes the provider to check that the container is running, which might be sufficient but I'm not sure.

If possible, for robustness I would recommend designing your software to be resilient to connection problems.
For example, the container you've called "backend" would ideally tolerate the Postgres server being unavailable and politely retry connecting until it succeeds. This can also be helpful if you need to restart the Postgres container later for any reason, so that the backend will automatically reconnect shortly after it begins running again.

This does not work, as the depends_on meta argument just ensures that the container runs, but it does not mean that the software inside the container is actually ready for service. Quite sad that this is not included or that there is a mechanism to make this more intuitive.
